# Error message design time only: "Cannot locate resource 'styles/buttonstyles.xaml'"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

A mysterious message comes up in the following scenario:
Cannot locate resource 'styles/buttonstyles.xaml'

This message only appears in design mode, and cannot be get ridden of. If I rebuild the solution the error message disappears, until I open the ApplicationWindow.xaml.

The environment is the following:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
...
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <controls:CustomToolbar Style="{StaticResource ToolBarStyle}"/>
</Grid>
...
```

Problem points to the **controls:CustomToolbar** part.

CustomToolbar.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Frontend.Views.Controls.CustomToolbar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Frontend.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="800">
    
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styles/ButtonStyles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Views/GlobalStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ToolbarButton}" Command="{Binding NewProjectCommand}" ToolTip="New project">
            <Image Source="{StaticResource NewProject}" Stretch="None" />
        </Button>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Separator Height="20" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

If I change the order of the merged dictionaries, the error message switches to the first one.

What I have tried:

- Every link that google and stackoverflow has
- Clean Solution, including deleting bin, obj, .vs folders, then rebuild.
- Restart Visual Studio, restart PC
- Using fully qualified URI -> Does not work, these dictionaries are in the current assembly.
- Every ResourceDictionary's properties are set to BuildAction:Page, and MSBuild:Compile

If I don't use any ResourceDictionary the error message does not come.

**EDIT1:**

This is the project structure:
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh937.png)

ResourceDict usages:
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGQcu.png)

Thanks,
Norbert

Comment: What is the project/s structure, where are the things placed and where be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I solved this problem by refactoring mergedDictionary includes, by the following way:

- Removed every MergedDictionary from every control, style, etc.
- Move all of them to the App.xaml (to the root)

Code:

```
<Application x:Class="Frontend.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styles/Images.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styles/ButtonStyles.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styles/MenuStyles.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styles/ToolbarStyles.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Views/GlobalStyles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

My very experienced friend said:
This could happen if you swap the include order in the xaml files, for example:

Style1 is defined in **Resdic1**.
Style2 is defined in **Resdic2**.
Style2 uses Style1.

However the order in the merged dictionary is the following:

- Resdic2
- Resdic1

Answer (score 0):

You have not introduced the namespace where

`<controls:CustomToolbar Style="{StaticResource ToolBarStyle}"/>` is to the program.

***Add the following line to the Window tag***

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Your name space.Views.Controls"
```

See where the `CustomToolbar` is located, enter it according to the code above

Comment: The problem is still present. I extended the Question with additional information.

Comment: @Behold The Light system CustomToolbar does not recognize you. Introduce it to the program

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly.

Comment: Did you give the system a CustomToolbar name space? I explained in the post.

Comment: Yes I did, and I get this error message: "Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'Frontend.Views.Controls' that could not be found."